# Simple Arm couldn't launch, ubuntu 18

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys I have the newest ubuntu with ROS melodic, and I followed the instruction to installed as much as I could. The turtle tutorial works. And I install the simple arm, but it coudn't be launched. Would you mind help me a little, newbie here.
Many thanks, here is the printout from the

```
$ roslaunch simple_arm robot_spawn.launch

[ INFO] [1531799911.413940202]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.

[ INFO] [1531799911.415080431]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)

  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)

  Value in failed request:  0x0

  Serial number of failed request:  26

  Current serial number in output stream:  27

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument

Aborted (core dumped)

[gazebo-5] process has died [pid 16226, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /home/bill/catkin_ws/src/simple_arm/worlds/willow_garage.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/bill/.ros/log/aaa40ba8-8975-11e8-bffa-b88198114d56/gazebo-5.log].

log file: /home/bill/.ros/log/aaa40ba8-8975-11e8-bffa-b88198114d56/gazebo-5*.log

[INFO] [1531799912.009320, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros parameter robot_description

[INFO] [1531799912.025701, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument

Aborted (core dumped)

[gazebo_gui-6] process has died [pid 16233, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient 
__name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/bill/.ros/log/aaa40ba8-8975-11e8-bffa-b88198114d56/gazebo_gui-6.log].

log file: /home/bill/.ros/log/aaa40ba8-8975-11e8-bffa-b88198114d56/gazebo_gui-6*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297635/simple-arm-couldn%27t-launch,-ubuntu-18/) by [billchenxi](https://answers.ros.org/users/36504/billchenxi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anukriti](https://answers.ros.org/users/79683/anukriti/) on 2021-10-21**:
How did you install simple arm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just need to restart!

---

Originally posted by [billchenxi](https://answers.ros.org/users/36504/billchenxi/) with karma: 16 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0